# In Flash Point: Fire Rescue can you "pick up" a victim marker with the Ambulance by driving past it?

Tags: flash-point

Quite often while playing Flash Point: Fire Rescue my wife and I end up carrying a victim from the building through an exterior wall that has been destroyed. We know an ambulance can only drive to certain parking spots. If a victim is outside of the building, can we "pick up" that victim with the ambulance as we drive past it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot

The rules say that:

> In the Experienced game Victims must be carried to the Ambulance to be Rescued

And

> Vehicles may be driven by 
>   the Firefighters, but only to their respective parking spot

So an Ambulance can only be in a parking spot and you have to carry victims to the Ambulance. You need to bring the victims to the parking spot.